# python-docx WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE not work

Tags: python, python-docx

Very simple code:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_LINE_SPACING
from docx import Document

document = Document('demo.docx')
smi_line = document.add_paragraph('test line spacing')
smi_line.line_spacing_rule = WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE
document.save('demo.docx')
```

When i open **demo.docx** in MS Word i see that line spacing is multiple. What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `.line_spacing_rule` property on the `ParagraphFormat` object:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_LINE_SPACING
from docx import Document

document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('test line spacing')
paragraph.paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule = WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE
document.save('demo.docx')
```